# Model Doesn't Learn When Used With Grid Search

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, gridsearchcv

I have built two models, the first works fine, the code is

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(25, input_dim=8, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
model.add(Dense(25, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
model.add(Dense(25, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='tanh'))
opt = SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.9)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=opt)

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=1000, verbose=1)
train_mse = model.evaluate(X_train, y_train, verbose=0)
test_mse = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
```

I believe the next model below, implemented using grid search, is identical. Except it doesn't seem to learn, the loss starts off astronomical and barely decreases. The code is:

```
def build_classifier():
  classifier = Sequential()
  classifier.add(Dense(25, input_dim=8, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
  classifier.add(Dense(25, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
  classifier.add(Dense(25, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
  classifier.add(Dense(1, activation='tanh'))
  opt = SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.9)
  classifier.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=opt, metrics=["accuracy"])
  return classifier

classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn = build_classifier)
parameters = {'epochs':[1000]}
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator = classifier,
                          param_grid = parameters,
                          cv = 5)
grid_search = grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
best_parameters = grid_search.best_params_
best_accuracy = grid_search.best_score_
```

^I am aware I am not actually tuning any hyper parameters here. I kept reduce and removing the hyper parameters I was tuning, in the hope I could identify the problem.

I have cross_categorical models using the same data, and do not have this problem (making sure my model is reasonable with test train split, then remaking with grid search for tuning hyper parameters).

I cannot see what the difference between the two models would be, that allows the first to learn reasonably but the second to not work at all.